# React: Function call portal does not contain target

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

we got the issue that a `useReducer` is closing a Portal in our Application and we can not controll the behaviour of it.
https://codesandbox.io/s/724ozpxxk1
As you can see, when you click on the trigger a `<Portal />` gets opened and a `handleOutsideMouseClick` gets appended.
When you click on the first row, the handler correctly checks that the clicked target is a children of the portal.
But as soon as you dispatch an action passed from the father, does not recognize that the clicked target is a children of the portal.

Here it's passed as a prop, so Context (Provider/Consumer) is not the problem.
https://codesandbox.io/s/mj7y4v2mnj

And here its a `useState` passed as a prop, so i dont know where to search next... 
https://codesandbox.io/s/74860klz3j

Answer (score 0):

The problem in you case is that you render the `Trigger` component directly in the App component which will re-render when the content value changes or reducer state changes and due to this some of your other logic to handle Portal open state fails which causes your Portal to close. Rendering your component like below works

```
const App = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { foo: "bar" });

  const appContextValue = useMemo(
    () => ({
      ...state,
      dispatch
    }),
    [state.foo]
  );

  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={appContextValue}>
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <App>
    <Trigger overlay={<Overlay />}>
      <div>trigger</div>
    </Trigger>
  </App>,
  rootElement
);
```

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/p9kqvxp59q)**